# Checking if object in Open Street Maps is a building

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, openstreetmap

I'm using Leaflet library in my ReactJS app and I wonder if there is a simple way to recognize if object clicked by user is a building. 
Idea that came up to my mind is to check map colour under clicked position. 
Does it make sense?
I appreciate your help.

*Colleagues in comments advised to give some use-case:*

App I'm working on is meant to mark antique buildings with elevation in bad shape so city architecture management had simpler job of searching for them.
Every user of this App can mark such building. To prevent hooligans from corrupting data with senseless points on map I wanted to validate as a first step if clicked point is a building.

I hope it will clarify problem a little bit.

Comment: What exactly is your use-case and desired final result here? I don't know of a way to check the color of the pixel being clicked, but if there is a way to do so, I doubt that there is a consistent way of associating a color or colors to whether the click is happening upon a building. You should also post your code and/org attempts up to this point.

Comment: I just want to check if user clicks on a building or not.
That's it. I don't have code that checks colour because it was just an idea so far.

Comment: You are creating an app that tells the user if they've clicked a building or not? Can't they see that they've clicked a building? My point in asking you to clarify your end goal is because I don't believe that is any way of doing what you're asking, at least no simple--by a long shot--way. If you know you're end-goal, that may inspire an idea of accomplishing what you want. Posting your current code is in the stackoverflow question guidelines because it helps us help you. This question is currently too broad.

Comment: You might get a broader viewpoint if you post this question on [gis.se] - but as @DevinFields writes, best to share your use case rather than just your implementation idea. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I wonder if there is a *simple* way to recognize if object clicked by user is a building.

No.

You basically want to run arbitrary point-in-polygon queries against OSM's building dataset, and I will presume that you don't want to host that dataset yourself.

The simpl**est** way to do this is to perform queries to an [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) server, passing a [`is_in`](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Query_for_areas_.28is_in.29) query and [filtering](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#By_tag_.28has-kv.29) by the [`building` tag key](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:building). The OSM website's [query feature functionality](https://blog.openstreetmap.org/2014/12/01/new-query-feature/) uses [such a technique](https://github.com/openstreetmap/openstreetmap-website/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/index/query.js#L261).

With this technique you won't have to worry about hosting the data, just about creating the right Overpass API query. Please bear in mind that the Overpass API servers are run by volunteers and [their resources are limited](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API#Public_Overpass_API_instances).

The second simplest way would be to download a OSM extract of you area of interest, and run the point-in-polygon queries yourself, by whatever means you like (PostGIS' `ST_Intersect`, turf.js, etc etc).

If you will be using Leaflet, another approach would be to use [vector tiles](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid), and set it up in such a way that the buildings thematic layer is interactive. This will require you to be aware of the limitations of the vector tile servers.

> Idea that came up to my mind is to check map colour under clicked position.

That is unreliable. Think about labels on top of buildings, or the colour of the edge of the building area, or buildings that don't render with the standard colour (e.g. places of worship, monuments).